# Error: Failed to load skin for error: NSURLError Domain

Tags: ios, ipad, nsurl, nsurlerrordomain

Does anyone know anything about this error: "Error: Failed to load skin for error: NSURLError Domain"

After trying to open a download link in order to reskin an app on an iPad, I get the above error. The interesting/annoying thing about this is that it is not followed by any error code, which is making it difficult to search for in the forums as all of the results that I get include an error code e.g.: "NSURLErrorDomain error -1012"

The re-skinning has worked for another skin, but not for the one I'm working on now.

Any ideas? Any recommendations for diagnostic tests etc.?

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLErrorDomain` error -1012 is `kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`, meaning that the server issued an authentication challenge that was subsequently rejected. Causes for rejection vary, but could be invalid password supplied, or because the authentication challenge was not handled at all. It's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but error -1012 was just an example of what I'm not seeing. My problem is that there is no error code, I just get "Error: Failed to load skin for error: NSURLError Domain". Have you ever seen that before?

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved this now. Turned out that the URL I was using was simply incorrect.